# How to disable location service programmatically?

Tags: android, service, location

Is there any way to disable google location service programmatically?
I want to write an app to turn it off with a widget.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It must exist, I have the Power Control widget which does just that.

Comment: The power control widget is a system app, so it can modify the location providers string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there any way to disable google location service programmatically?

No, sorry, you cannot disable GPS, etc. programmatically, except via an app installed on the system partition or signed by the firmware's signing key. IOW, you need a rooted phone.

Comment: Thanks, managed to do it with root by modifying location providers string.

Answer (score 3):

As far as i know, the LocationManager is a system service that can not be turned off. Though, you can disable all the location providers that the service uses, such as Wireless location, GPS, etc.

Comment: Thank you too for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the `UiAutomater`, you can turn off Location Services by simulating a click on the **Location** option in the *Quick Settings*. The filter logic may be platform dependent. You may analyse the view hierarchy using the [`uiautomatorviewer`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/testing-support-library/index.html#UIAutomator).

i.e.

```
UiDevice.getInstance(getInstrumentation()).openQuickSettings();
UiDevice.getInstance(getInstrumentation()).findObject(new UiSelector().descriptionContains("Location").className(ViewGroup.class)).click();
```

**build.gradle**

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.1.2'
```

Comment: Totally incorrect, this answer is for a connected test.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is, No. But if you really need to turn it off, you can prompt the user to do it:

```
LocationManager loc = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService( Context.LOCATION_SERVICE );
        if( loc.isProviderEnabled(android.location.LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER ) )
        {
            Toast.makeText( this, "Please turn off GPS", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent myIntent = new Intent( Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS );
            startActivity(myIntent);

        }
        else
        {

        // Do nothing   
        }
```

This might not help your situation but is the only way I know of changing the settings.

Comment: Thank you! I was thinking more about the network determined location of the user than of gps.

Comment: Ah my interpretation of the question was clearly wrong. But still a useful snippet of code